# how to Replace null with zero in pivot SQL query

Tags: sql-server

I am trying to fetch Year wise and month wise sales like

```
 select * from
 (
 select year(InvDt) as [Year], left(datename(Month,InvDt), 3) as [Month], 
 InvAmnt as Amount
 from tblInvoice where TenantId =-xxxxxxxx
 ) as Inv
 pivot
 (sum(Amount) for [Month] in(Jan, Feb, Mar, Apr, May, Jun, Jul, Aug, Sep, 
  Oct, Nov, [Dec])) as pvt
```

[image]
But here so many null is coming so I want to replace these null with zero.
please help me.

Comment: have you tried COALESCE or ISNULL?

Comment: yeah I Tried but its isnull(sum(Amount),0)  and coalesce(sum(Amount),0) but shwoing error we can't use I think it in pivot

Comment: Try `SUM(ISNULL(Amount, 0))`. `ISNULL` should be inside `SUM`.

Comment: 'isnull' is not a recognized aggregate function. error

Comment: Amount is already not null, it can never be null but sum(Amount) is coming null like for Feb 2014

Comment: no this is correct, 2010, 2012, 2013 for feb month here amount is coming but Feb 2014 it's coming null

Comment: Please see the result i have attached one pic

Comment: ISNULL(VALUE,REPLACE) should work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
create table tblInvoice (InvDt date, TenantId int, InvAmnt numeric)
insert into tblInvoice values ('20180601',1,1),('20180601',1,1),('20180601',1,1),('20180501',1,1), ('20180401',1,1)

SELECT Year
     , COALESCE(Jan   ,0) Jan
     , COALESCE(Feb   ,0) Feb
     , COALESCE(Mar   ,0) Mar
     , COALESCE(Apr   ,0) Apr
     , COALESCE(May   ,0) May
     , COALESCE(Jun   ,0) Jun
     , COALESCE(Jul   ,0) Jul
     , COALESCE(Aug   ,0) Aug
     , COALESCE(Sep   ,0) Sep
     , COALESCE(Oct   ,0) Oct
     , COALESCE(Nov   ,0) Nov
     , COALESCE(Dec   ,0) Dec
  FROM (   SELECT YEAR(InvDt)                     AS Year
                , LEFT(DATENAME(MONTH, InvDt), 3) AS Month
                , InvAmnt                         AS Amount
             FROM tblInvoice
            WHERE TenantId = 1) AS Inv
  PIVOT (   SUM(Amount)
            FOR Month IN (Jan, Feb, Mar, Apr, May, Jun, Jul, Aug, Sep, Oct, Nov, Dec)) AS pvt;
```

Comment: Dmitrij Kultasev your answer also works for me.Thanks

Answer (score 1):

So Answer is this but it's too long, something we must have another solution but I am not getting right now

```
select [Year], isnull(Jan, 0) as Jan,isnull(Feb,0) as Feb, isnull(Mar, 0) as 
Mar, isnull(Apr, 0) as Apr, isnull(May,0) as May, 
isnull(Jun,0) as Jun, isnull(Jul,0) as Jul, isnull(Aug,0) as Aug, 
isnull(Sep,0) as Sep,isnull(Oct,0) as Oct, isnull(Nov,0) as Nov, 
isnull([Dec],0) as Dec
from
(
select year(InvDt) as [Year], left(datename(Month,InvDt), 3) as [Month], 
InvAmnt as Amount
from tblInvoice where TenantId =-xxxxxxx
) as Inv
pivot
(sum(Amount) for [Month] in(Jan, Feb, Mar, Apr, May, Jun, Jul, Aug, Sep, 
Oct, Nov, [Dec])) as pvt
```

Thanks Mazhar by your solution my mind was opened and works this.

Comment: This is the same as @Dmitrij's answer, just structured differently. ISNULL and COALESCE in this context are same, but ISNULL isn't support at all or the same way on other database providers.

Answer (score 0):

Just add a coalesce statement in a subquery to replace nulls on zero:

```
 select * from
     (
     select year(InvDt) as [Year], left(datename(Month,InvDt), 3) as [Month], 
     coalesce(InvAmnt, 0) as Amount
     from tblInvoice where TenantId =-xxxxxxxx
     ) as Inv
     pivot
     (sum(Amount) for [Month] in(Jan, Feb, Mar, Apr, May, Jun, Jul, Aug, Sep, 
      Oct, Nov, [Dec])) as pvt)
```